Retrieve pull request creator and approver
I currently have a GitHub workflow that is triggered on push to main. This builds and deploys the artifact and so on. Now I want to log additional information with another action. I want to save the person who created the preceding pull request and the person who approved the pull request.
What is the best way to get this information? It feels like the execution of the workflow should remain on push. But to get this information I would have to start the workflow as soon as the PR has been approved & merged. What would be the best approach from a design point of view?

You need to use pull_request trigger for your workflow and specify closed as a type of the event. This trigger makes pull_request event available to the workflow that indicates whether pull request was merged or not. You can use this flag to only run your workflow if a PR was merged.
To get creator and approver, you can use GitHHub CLI and call Get Pull Request API and then List Reviews for a Pull Request API
name: Pull Request Closed Workflow

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - closed

jobs:
  pr-merged:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Extract creator and approver
        run: |
          # Get PR creator
          gh api /repos/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/pulls/${{ github.event.pull_request.number }} | jq -r '.user.login'

          # Get PR approver
          gh api /repos/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/pulls/${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}/reviews | jq -r 'map(select(.state == 'APPROVED')) | .[0].user.login'
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}


A few remarks: 1. You don't need to check out the repo (but you should use v4 if you did). 2. The author is available directly in the event object: github.event.pull_request.user.login 3. There are convenience functions in gh like gh --repo "$GITHUB_REPOSITORY" pr view "$number" --json reviews --jq '...'

Thank you for insightful feedback. Agreed about checkout - @v4 does not cause a warning.  No need to checkout a repo in the first place. However, I am not totally sold on the gh flags. They look more complex than a direct api call and less self documenting.

Using gh subcommands is probably a matter of taste; they just wrap the API at the end of the day anyway.

Agreed. Regarding github.event.pull_request.user.login. Are you sure that this is the person who created the PR and not the person who triggered the event? I could not determine that from the docs and chose to go to the source by calling a get pull request API.

The triggering user is always in github.event.sender. I'm 99% that pull_request.user the creator of the PR.

I am still not sure: Would it be better to create a new step that is retrieving corresponding pull request (and its creator/approver) of the merge to main via API? I found out that you can get the merge and therefore are able to retrieve all dis information. Would simplify the complete process (build, raise version, deploy, etc.) because a lot of the typical CI/CD steps do not relate to the pull_request action...

I am not sure I understand what you mean. I added a step that only runs when a pull request is merged. It does retrieve pull request via API. You can find creator under .user.login in the pull request object. However, you can not find approver in the pull request object. You need to read pull request reviews and find the review that approved this pull request. That review will contain approver under .user.login By the way, you can add on: push: trigger to your workflow so that you can build branches. However, push event will not give you pull request number.
